# Where to add a caption and a reference to a tabbing&fbox&minipage

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, boxes, minipage, tabbing

I put some texts enclosed within `tabbing`, embedded in `fbox` and `minipage`:

```
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}%
\begin{tabbing}
\quad \= \quad \= \quad \= \quad \= \quad \= \hspace{5cm} \= \\[-\baselineskip]\kill
 ...
 ...
\end{tabbing}
\end{minipage}}\hfill
```

The question is... if I want to put a caption for the whole text, just under and outside the frame, and make it a reference. Do where should I put this `\caption{acap}` and `\reference{aref}`?

Could anyone help? Thank you very much!

**Edit1:** Following the second proposition of @Stefan Kottwitz, I have the following code, which prints the two minipages on the same height. The problem now is that, before adding the outer minipage of the first minipage, there was space between two sides, and their positions were all right. But now, the right minipage has moved a little bit to the left, so that the space has disappeared... Could anyone help? Thank you!

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}%
\centering
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}%
\begin{tabbing}
\quad \= \quad \= \quad \= \quad \= \quad \= \hspace{5cm} \= \\[-\baselineskip]\kill
...
\end{tabbing}
\end{minipage}}\hfill
\captionof{table}{A Testbox}\label{testbox}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
...
\end{minipage}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `figure` or `table` environment, using LaTeX's floating objects capabilities:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}%
\begin{tabbing}
\quad \= \quad \= \quad \= \quad \= \quad \= \hspace{5cm} \= \\[-\baselineskip]\kill
 ...
 ...
\end{tabbing}
\end{minipage}}\hfill
\caption{A Testbox}
\label{testbox}
\end{table}
See box \ref{testbox}.
\end{document}
```

If you don't want the objects to float, but need captions and cross-referencing, you could use the `caption` package and its command `\captionof`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}%
\begin{tabbing}
\quad \= \quad \= \quad \= \quad \= \quad \= \hspace{5cm} \= \\[-\baselineskip]\kill
 ...
 ...
\end{tabbing}
\end{minipage}}\hfill
\captionof{table}{A Testbox}
\label{testbox}
\end{center}
See box \ref{testbox}.
\end{document}
```

I used a `center` environment, you could also use just another minipage around instead. I chose `table` instead of `figure` since it's a tabular object. You could also declare your own caption type.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment... my `minipage` is on the left half side of the page, but following your method, the `caption` is in the center of the page, how could I just put the `caption` under the minipage?

Comment: @SoftTimur: no problem ... I guess you would like to center the caption below the minipage, but outside the box. So, put another minipage around the box, use `\centering` at the begin and `\captionof` before the end of the outer minipage.

Comment: Now it is better, but still, the right minipage has moved a little bit to the right --- there is no more space between the 2 minipages... I am going to add my code in the initial post immediately

Comment: @SoftTimur: Now you have a follow-up question which is about positioning two minipages. It's getting complicated if you mix it here into the original question & answer. In such cases, it would be better to post a separate question with an example on the new basis. I guess you just should move the \hfill between the two outer minipages, not keeping it inside an inner minipage.

Comment: Well... no deed to post another question... it is indeed \hfill which should be after the outer minipage, instead of inner minipage, thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Another way to achieve your objective is to use the `float` package, which lets you create a custom environment akin to the `figure` and `table` environments, but with a box drawn around its contents. The new environment -- let's call it `boxx` because `box` is a reserved word -- can be given labels and thus also cross-referenced, exactly like you would do with figures and tables. In addition, if needed, all boxes (or boxxes) can be listed in the document's table of contents using the command `\listofboxxes`.

Consider the following code (again, please forgive the awkward name `boxx`, but `box` is a reserved word in TeX and LaTeX):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float,lipsum}
\floatstyle{boxed}
\newfloat{boxx}{thb}{lob}
\floatname{boxx}{Box}

\begin{document}

\begin{boxx}
\caption{Lipsum, Para 1}\label{box:1}
\lipsum[1]
\end{boxx}

\begin{boxx}
\caption{Lipsum, Para 2} \label{box:2}    
\lipsum[2]
\end{boxx}

And here are cross-references to Boxes \ref{box:1} and \ref{box:2}.
\end{document}
```

If all you want is to restyle the appearance of LaTeX's `table` environment by placing a box around its contents (rather than creating a whole new environment), you could still load the `float` package in the preamble and then insert the commands `\floatstyle{boxed}` and `\restylefloat{table}`, and all table environments will automatically be boxed rather than plain.